# csv file to list within dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, dictionary

```
with open('exoplanets.csv') as infile:
    planets = {} 
    lines = infile.readline()
    for line in infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        number =  [line]

        methods, number, orbital_period, mass, distance, year = (s.strip(' ') for s in line.split(','))
        planets[methods] = (number, orbital_period, mass, distance, year)
        print(planets)
```

my code currently looks like that with the sample input:

[image]

and my output looks like this:

[image]

however, I want it to look like this:

```
{
  "Radial Velocity" : {"number":[1,1,1], "orbital_period":[269.3, 874.774, 763.0], "mass":[7.1, 2.21, 2.6], "distance":[77.4, 56.95, 19.84], "year":[2006.0, 2008.0, 2011.0] } , 
  "Transit" : {"number":[1,1,1], "orbital_period":[1.5089557, 1.7429935, 4.2568], "mass":[], "distance":[200.0, 680.0], "year":[2008.0, 2008.0, 2008.0] }
}
```

can someone help me

Comment: Are the list in the dictionary item as  `"orbital_period":[269.3, 874.774, 763.0]` ever 3 elements long?

Comment: I understand this dictionary in the first line of your desired output: `"Radial Velocity" : {"number":[1,1,1], "orbital_period":[269.3, 874.774, 763.0], "mass":[7.1, 2.21, 2.6], "distance":[77.4, 56.95, 19.84], "year":[2006.0, 2008.0, 2011.0] }`. But where do the numbers it the second line `"Transit" : {"number":[1,1,1], "orbital_period":[1.5089557, 1.7429935, 4.2568], "mass":[], "distance":[200.0, 680.0], "year":[2008.0, 2008.0, 2008.0] }` come from? It seems to me they are not present in the input file...

Comment: @AndreaBlengino its further down the list, i only pasted a fraction of the list. and it was just a sample output, I believe it should be more than 3 elements, as in every single block of the column.

Comment: Ok, but from the info above I have the instructions to construct the first line of your required output; I have no instructions to construct the second line because I do not know its format in the source data.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ff4G_m8XQ8GdAJTdswEGEjDKK1t_QTnuItDx_zYquxc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: it was orginally a .csv file but i just formatted in google sheets for easy access. the assignment does not want me to use neither panda or the csv module

Comment: “Easy access” is posting text for the sample data instead of images so we can use cut and paste to test solutions. Do not post images of text.

Comment: are you able to copy-paste from the spreadsheet

Comment: Looks like homework.  There's another question with the same data: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62248605/235698

Comment: I added an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code:

```
# import nan
from math import nan

# define source file
filename = 'EXOPLANETS.CSV - Sheet1.csv'

# read source file
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()

# prepare output dictionary
output = {}

# read line by line
for idx, line in enumerate(data, 0):

    # split columns
    items = line.replace('\n', '').split(',')

    # extract inner dictionary's keys in a list: 'number', orbital_period', 'mass', 'distance', 'year'
    if idx == 0:
        values = [key for key in items[1:]]

    else:

        # add main key to the output dictionary: 'Radial Velocity', 'Imaging', 'Transit'
        if items[0] not in output.keys():
            output[items[0]] = {key : [] for key in values}

        # add value to the inner dictionary
        for jdx, key in enumerate(values, 1):

            # if the value is a valid number, convert it in float
            if items[jdx] != '':
                output[items[0]][key].append(float(items[jdx]))

            # if the value is not a valid number (empty cell), add a 'nan'
            else:
                output[items[0]][key].append(nan)

for items in output.items():
    print(items)
```

It will perform your task without using neither `pandas` or `csv`:

```
("Radial Velocity" : {"number":[1.0, 1.0, ...], "orbital_period":[269.3, 874.774, ...], "mass":[7.1, 2.21, ...], "distance":[77.4, 56.95, ...], "year":[2006.0, 2008.0, ...] ),

("Imaging" : {"number":[1.0, 1.0, ...], "orbital_period":[nan, nan, ...], "mass":[nan, nan, ...], "distance":[45.52, 165.0, ...], "year":[2005.0, 2007.0, ...] ),

("Transit" : {"number":[1.0, 1.0, ...], "orbital_period":[1.5089557, 1.7429935, ...], "mass":[nan, nan, ...], "distance":[nan, 200.0, ...], "year":[2008.0, 2008.0, ...] })
```

If the value in the source data is an empty cell, the code above will add a `nan` to the `output`. If this is an unwanted behavior and you want to jump the empy cells, use this code below:

```
# define source file
filename = 'EXOPLANETS.CSV - Sheet1.csv'

# read source file
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()

# prepare output dictionary
output = {}

# read line by line
for idx, line in enumerate(data, 0):

    # split columns
    items = line.replace('\n', '').split(',')

    # extract inner dictionary's keys in a list: 'number', orbital_period', 'mass', 'distance', 'year'
    if idx == 0:
        values = [key for key in items[1:]]

    else:

        # add main key to the output dictionary: 'Radial Velocity', 'Imaging', 'Transit'
        if items[0] not in output.keys():
            output[items[0]] = {key : [] for key in values}

        # add value to the inner dictionary
        for jdx, key in enumerate(values, 1):

            # if the value is a valid number, convert it in float
            if items[jdx] != '':
                output[items[0]][key].append(float(items[jdx]))

for items in output.items():
    print(items)
```

Comment: Thank you! your help is very much appreciated!!

Comment: following items[0] in output, it is a comma, how do I make it a semi-colon

Comment: I think you should open an other question for this in order to keep the site clean