# How to return a specific data structure with inner dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file (image attached) and to take the CSV file and create a dictionary of lists with the format "`{method},{number},{orbital_period},{mass},{distance},{year}`" .

So far I have code :

```html
import csv

with open('exoplanets.csv') as inputfile : 
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
    inputm = list(reader)
    print(inputm)
```

but my output is coming out like `['Radial Velocity', '1', '269.3', '7.1', '77.4', '2006']`

when I want it to look like :

```
 "Radial Velocity" : {"number":[1,1,1], "orbital_period":[269.3, 874.774, 763.0], "mass":[7.1, 2.21, 2.6], "distance":[77.4, 56.95, 19.84], "year":[2006.0, 2008.0, 2011.0] } , "Transit" : {"number":[1,1,1], "orbital_period":[1.5089557, 1.7429935, 4.2568], "mass":[], "distance":[200.0, 680.0], "year":[2008.0, 2008.0, 2008.0] }
```

[image: here]

Any ideas on how I can alter my code?

Comment: whats your file content

Comment: File content : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PnQzoefx-IiB3D5BKVOrcawoVFLIPVXQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Looks like homework.  There's another question with the same data: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62239961/235698

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use Pandas, maybe something like this is what you're looking for:

```
import csv

with open('exoplanets.csv') as inputfile : 
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
    inputm = list(reader)

    header = inputm.pop(0)
    del header[0] # probably you don't want "#method"

    # create and populate the final dictionary
    data = {}
    for row in inputm:
        if row[0] not in data:
            data[row[0]] = {h:[] for h in header}

        for i, h in enumerate(header):
            data[row[0]][h].append(row[i+1])

print(data)
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can get rid of the quotation marks inside of the inner list. For example, go from 'number':['1','2','3'] to 'number':[1,2,3]

Comment: Yes, inside the `append()` function near the bottom, you can try replacing `row[i+1]` with `float(row[i+1]) if row[i+1] else row[i+1]`. So this will cast string numbers to float. Note that empty values will still be `''`, unless you change the `else` to something different.

Answer (score 2):

Hey SKR01 welcome to Stackoverflow!

I would suggest working with the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library. It is meant for table like contents that you have there. What you are then looking for is a groupby on your #method column.

```
import pandas as pd

def remove_index(row):
    d = row._asdict()
    del d["Index"]
    return d


df = pd.read_csv("https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1PnQzoefx-IiB3D5BKVOrcawoVFLIPVXQ")

{row.Index : remove_index(row) for row in df.groupby('#method').aggregate(list).itertuples()}
```

The only thing that remains is removing the nan values from the resulting dict.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit complex, and I'm questioning why you want the data this way, but this should get you the output format you want without requiring any external libraries like Pandas.

```py
import csv

with open('exoplanets.csv') as input_file: 
    rows = list(csv.DictReader(input_file))

    # Create the data structure
    methods = {d["#method"]: {} for d in rows}

    # Get a list of fields, trimming off the method column
    fields = list(rows[1])[1:]

    # Fill in the data structure
    for method in methods:
        methods[method] = {
            # Null-trimmed version of listcomp
            # f: [r[f] for r in rows if r["#method"] == method and r[f]]
            f: [r[f] for r in rows if r["#method"] == method]
            for f
            in fields
        }
```

**Note:** This could be one multi-tiered list/dict comprehension, but I've broken it apart for clarity.